# Spring Authorization Server - Create Users

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

Currently, i have a Spring Authorization Server that handles all the Oauth2 flow.This authorization server connects to a database of users.

However, i wish to have a some sort of register user endpoint , or even change name/password.

Is there any way to do this on the authorization server ? Or should a new microservice be created that connects to this database and creates users, changes password/names and so on?

Answer (score 1):

It's not built-in to the framework, so you would need to implement these features on your own.